# How to get search box value with event listener and log it

Tags: javascript

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar");

let searchQuery;

searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter" && searchBar.value != "") {
        location.href = 'pages/results/results.html';
        searchQuery = searchBar.value;
    }
    // get value entered and show on results.html
    // results for: "query"
})

console.log(searchQuery); // not working
```

This logs undefined because the event loop keeps going. How do I wait for the person to press enter and then log the value after that. I do not want to put the `console.log(searchQuery)` in the function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is a scope problem, you can't avoid to console.log inside the function. you can create another function and pass the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `console.log` function inside the event handler so it runs when the event handler is fired. Right now the `console.log` function runs once once when the script is loaded (logging `undefined`) but has nothing to trigger it again. Try this:

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar");

let searchQuery;

searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter" && searchBar.value != "") {
        location.href = 'pages/results/results.html';
        searchQuery = searchBar.value;
    }
    
    console.log(searchQuery)
})
```

OR like this if you only want it to fire when the key pressed is Enter && `searchBar.value`:

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar");

let searchQuery;

searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter" && searchBar.value != "") {
        location.href = 'pages/results/results.html';
        searchQuery = searchBar.value;
        console.log(searchQuery)
    }
})
```